# PouchDB how to check if localDB is up-to-date with remoteDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

How do i check if my localDB is up-to-date with the remoteDB? If I use .info() on both the update_seq is never the same even after i synced already. So are there some values I can compare, to see if I'm up-to-date?

```js
// local info
adapter: "websql"
auto_compaction: true
db_name: "mydbname1"
doc_count: 1771
sqlite_plugin: false
update_seq: 1781
websql_encoding: "UTF-8"

// remote info
adapter: "http"
auto_compaction: false
committed_update_seq: 1790
compact_running: false
data_size: 2593483
db_name: "mydbname"
disk_format_version: 6
disk_size: 4292727
doc_count: 1771
doc_del_count: 0
host: "http://something.com"
instance_start_time: "1443599117360300"
purge_seq: 0
update_seq: 1790
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing live+retry replication, the `'paused'` event will occur *without* an error if the database sync is up-to-date. You can also do a [single-shot replication](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#single-shot-1) and it will resolve the promise when the replication is complete (which means immediately if it's already done).

The seqs and infos between two databases cannot be compared to figure out which one is up to date with another.

Comment: Is this clearly stated on the official documentation? I was about to ask the same question. I can't remember reading such thing on the official docs.